# Word-AddIn (VSTO) doesn't get the filepath from local OneDrive Folder

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in, onedrive

I'm trying to develop an Word-AddIn where I can upload a file, or where I could make changes to the file itself. I can do that with any File on the Local NTFS Windows Filesystem. But when a File is located to any "OneDrive"-Folder it won't work, as the file-Document path starts with:

```
https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/name_whatever/Documents
```

according to the return values of:

```
var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

        MessageBox.Show("Document Name : " + doc.Name);
        MessageBox.Show("Document Full Name : " + doc.FullName);
        MessageBox.Show("Document Path : " + doc.Path);
```

rather than expected to be:

```
C:\Users\myname\OneDrive-My_Company_Name\Documents
```

So basically the local folder is not callable. So does anybody has already faced this kind of issue?

Comment: **it won't work** what wont work ? In my opinion you don't need to know where the file is located. Are you unable to save the document after changing ? The call `Save` if you want to save a copy `SaveAs` if you want to save a copy in the same folder of the source doc you will need to check OneDrive API ; perhaps [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195891/saving-a-shared-docx-from-onedrive-to-original-onedrive-location-in-ms-word) will help

Comment: I don't want to `save` a document. All I want is, when the Document is open in Word, and I want to upload it to a webserver, or any other destination, the code of the Add-In will check the current location of the Document and then tries to get it and upload it to the destination (ex. Webpage - upload via POSTMethod). So in case the Document is on a Folder for example called `C:\TEMP` it is working without any issue. But when the File is in the Local OneDrive folder on the Box, it will end up in the described issue.

Comment: In your problem what I can't understand is where the actual issue is? You described "the code of the Add-In will check the current location of the Document" , "tries to get it" & "upload it to the destination" mainly 3 scenarios. Where the actual problem exist? Any code sample?

Comment: You can get the local path of your document with VBA using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457). I don't know how difficult it would be to port the code to .NET. If it is too difficult to port that solution, you could definitely do it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457), which is not 100% reliable though, but will still work in almost all real-world cases.

Comment: A VB.NET solution for this problem now exists [here](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/bc875f4f25e0e970c62959d3c59da1d6). The solution is a port of [this function](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d) originally written in VBA. Performance is a little worse than in the VBA version because some functionality of VBA is not available in V.NET and I didn't want to change the code too much to reduce the effort for porting. Maybe this can be further ported to C# without too much effort...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Save` or `SaveAs` methods of the `Document` to save the document on the local folder.

Comment: Why would I save the document which is already saved. I just opened it from OneDrive local folder via the Windows Explorer? Now I should save it again, where? In the same folder? Or in any other folder on Windows? These are additional steps I don't want to do.

Comment: To the temp folder, probably.

Comment: Have you tried the IO.FileInfo class, method DirectoryName?

Comment: And is the document opened under the protected mode?